# codeigniter help causing error while loading model

Tags: codeigniter

I am not sure whats wrong with my code.......it causing an error while loading model.......
please help...........
my controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Exams extends CI_Controller {
    public function index(){
        $ob = new exam_class();
        $ob->set_exam(0,'Html exam','1','20');
        $ob->create_exam();
        echo 'success';
    }
}

class exam_class{
    private $id;
    private $title;
    private $catagory;
    private $timeLength;

    function set_exam($id,$title,$catagory,$timeLength){
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->catagory = $catagory;
        $this->timeLength = $timeLength;
    }

    function create_exam(){
        $this->load->model('examModel');
        $this->examModel->create_exams($title,$catagory,$timeLength);
    }
}
```

model

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class ExamModel extends CI_Model {
    public function create_exams($title,$catagory,$timeLength){
        $data = array(
           'title' => $title ,
           'catagory' => $catagory ,
           'timeLength' => $timeLength
        );

        $this->db->insert('exams', $data);
    }
}
```

error
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: exam_class::$load

Filename: controllers/exams.php

Line Number: 26

Fatal error: Call to a member function model() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\exam\application\controllers\exams.php on line 26

Comment: why are you separating 2 classes in your controller?

Comment: I was using seperate class to make my site controllers simple.........just creating object of another class....

i am new in framework.......may be my method of coding is not right.... please give me any other suggestion....
i found the error my exam_class wasnt extending CI_Controller thnx for your help :)

Comment: Try with creating new instance to load model 
$ci = get_instance();
$ci->load->model('model name');

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't put more than one class in a file. Controller should be something like this.

```
class Exams extends CI_Controller {

    private $id;
    private $title;
    private $catagory;
    private $timeLength;
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('examModel');
    }

    public function index(){
        $this->set_exam(0,'Html exam','1','20');
        $this->create_exam();
        echo 'success';
    }   

    function set_exam($id,$title,$catagory,$timeLength){
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->catagory = $catagory;
        $this->timeLength = $timeLength;
    }

    function create_exam(){
        $this->examModel->create_exams($title,$catagory,$timeLength);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was using seperate class to make my site controllers simple.........just creating object of another class....

i am new in framework.......may be my method of coding is not right.... please give me any other suggestion....
i found the error my exam_class wasnt extending CI_Controller thnx for your help :)

Comment: Hey coder, follow shin's answer type of coding. It's the right approach to using codeigniter. What approach your are using coder is more like a C++ one, but in Codeigniter, you better use other member functions or create libraries and helpers for doing so. Also, always load your model in the constructor of the class.

Answer (score 1):

Along with @shin i want to  include that go to this file

```
....\testproject\application\config\autoload.php
```

and edit this to add your models

```
$autoload['model'] = array('modelName1','modelName2');
```

and to load the models from any time from any controller . This will automatically load your models.No need to add

```
 $this->load->model('modelName');
```

Comment: i found the error my exam_class wasnt extending  CI_Controller
thnx for your help :)

Comment: Everything should work fine. You can upload your test project in github then i will fix it ,thanx :)

Answer (score 0):

**Tip :** Keep it simple

In your controller :

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('examModel');
}

public function index()
{
    $exam_data = $this->process_exam_data(0,'Html exam','1','20');

    $insert_status = $this->examModel->create_exams($exam_data);

    if($insert_status===TRUE){
        echo "Exam Insert Successful!";
    }
    else{
        echo "Exam Insert Failed"; 
    }
}

public function process_exam_data($id, $title, $category, $timelength)
{
   // Do whatever you want with the data, calculations etc.

   // Prepare your data array same as to be inserted into db
   $final_data = array(
                   'title'      => $processed_title,
                   'catagory'   => $processed_category,
                   'timeLength' => $processed_time
                );
   return $final_data;
}
```

And in your model :

```
public function create_exams($data)
{
    $result = $this->db->insert('exams', $data); // Query builder functions return true on success and false on failure
    return $result;
}
```

Your `index` function is the main function which does the calling, whereas all the processing work is done in the `process_exam_data` function.

Have a nice day :)